# Bootstrap 3 forms - How to add bottom border to form fields? (To space them out)

Tags: html, css, ruby, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do you add a bottom border in bootstrap 3 to forms? Specifically when using embedded ruby? I simply cannot figure it out spent several hours and nothing seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

if I get it correctly this is what you are looking for.

```
form{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #777;
}
```

[a link] (http://jsfiddle.net/MQP2U/)

Let me know if you have some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the form-group with the border styling you want:

[**Example Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/LsAGkSLg69)

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group border">...</div>
```

CSS:

```
.border{
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  padding-bottom:20px
  }
```